# Find $\phi$ such that $\phi(X)\sim Γ(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, for $X\sim U(0,1)$

Tags: probability

So here is my attempt: Trying to use the following theorem to find such $\phi$: If $X$ has density function $f_{X}$ and $Y=\phi(X)$ and $\phi$ is strictly monotonic and differentiable function, then $f_{Y}(y)=f_{X}(\phi^{-1}(y))|\frac{dx}{dy}|$ is a density function of $Y$. Let's first look for an increasing $\phi$. After some calculations, we conclude that: $\phi^{-1}(y)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}e^{\frac{-y}{2}}dy$ from which, after substitution of $u=\sqrt{y}$, we obtain $\phi^{-1}(y)=2Φ(\sqrt{y})$, where $Φ$ is the standard normal distribution. We finally obtain $\phi(x)=[Φ^{-1}(\frac{x}{2})]^{2}$ for $x\in{(0,1)}$. But the solution guide indicates that $\phi(x)=[Φ^{-1}(x)]^{2}$ for $x\in{(-1,1)}$. What am I doing wrong ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Silly question, perhaps, but if $X \sim U(0,1)$, then how can we have $ x \in (-1,1)$?

Comment: Ignore the above comment -- or at least ignore the "silly question" bit:  I'm a bit rusty on all this.  Note that, even if $x=-1/2$ were in the support of your uniform variable, it isn't in the domain of $\Phi^{-1}$...

Comment: Your answer is closer to what I got, but I think you forgot something about the bounds of integration when you substituted $u = \sqrt{y}$.

Comment: It's indefinite integral. As far as it concerns the calculations : Set $u=\sqrt{y}\implies du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}dy$ and $y=u^{2}$. Hence, $\phi^{-1}(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int \frac{1}{u} e^{\frac{-u^{2}}{2}2udu=\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{\frac{-u^{2}}{2}} du$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll pick up where I think things may have gone astray.

With $\phi^{-1}$ assumed to be increasing, you have

$$ \frac{e^{-y/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sqrt{y}} = \frac{d}{dy} \phi^{-1}(y) $$

These are both functions of $y$ and are equal for $y > 0$. We'll see momentarily why it's important to note this domain restriction.

The LHS does look a lot like it can be transformed into the pdf of a standard normal random variable.  But to get that $\phi^{-1}$ out of the differentiation operator, it's not a matter of simply finding the antiderivative of both sides.  Note that $\Phi(z) \equiv P(Z\leq z)$ -- i.e.,

$$\Phi(z) = \int_{-\infty}^z f(t) dt, $$

where $f(t)$ is the pdf of a standard normal random variable.  Therefore, if we want to use the normal cdf, we have to take definite integrals of both sides.  But whereas $\Phi(z)$ is defined for all of $\mathbb{R}$, we're only looking at positive numbers.  And so --

\begin{align}
\int_0^t \frac{e^{-y/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sqrt{y}} dy &= \int_0^t \frac{d}{dy} \phi^{-1}(y) dy \\
\iff \; 2 \int_0^\sqrt{t} \frac{e^{-u^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} du &= \left[ \phi^{-1}(y) \right]_0^t  \\
\iff \; 2 \left[ \Phi(\sqrt{t}) - 1/2 \right] &= \phi^{-1}(t) - \phi^{-1}(0)
\end{align}

If $\phi^{-1}$ is increasing, we can figure out the exact value of $\phi^{-1}(0)$ by looking at the domain and range required for our transformation (or its inverse).  Once we do that, we'll have our answer :).

Note that, even though everything in the end is written in terms of $t$, those are actually values from our gamma distribution -- i.e., they're really $y$s.  Likewise, $\phi^{-1}(t)$ is an $x$-value.

---

Here's what the inverse transformation looks like -- a uniform distribution, I think, would be a bit more recognizable than a $\Gamma(1/2,1/2)$ -- as simulated in R:

```
> y <- rgamma(10000, .5, .5)
> x <- 2 * pnorm(sqrt(y)) - 1
> hist(x, freq=FALSE)
```

[image: simulated data]

Comment: In the last line of math text, shouldn't be $2[Φ(\sqrt{t})-\frac{1}{2}]=\phi^{1}(t)-\phi^{-1}(0)$ ? As far as it concerns the integral bounds, that was a good point and my knowledge in R is poor.

Comment: Yes!  I'll fix it now :).  In any case, I was unsure about my answer too, so I generated some data in R and plotted it; it looked pretty good.

Comment: Considering the domain, which will be $(0,1)$ and $\phi^{-1}(0)=0$ we obtain that $\phi(t)=[Φ^{-1}(\frac{t+1}{2})]^2$ for $t\in{[0,1]}$ which indeed is $Γ(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: Exactly.  And if we choose $\phi^{-1}$ to be decreasing, we get $2 \Phi(\sqrt{t}) - 1 = 1 - \phi^{-1}(t)$, which resolves in a similar fashion :).

Comment: Yes true, probably the solution in the textbook is wrong, as I checked $Φ^{-1}(x)^{2}\sim \frac{1}{2} Γ(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})\sim Γ(\frac{1}{2},1)$ apart from the domain. In any case, thank you very much for your time and effort :)

Comment: You're welcome!  It was a fun problem :).